# T-SQL - Total SUM Rows and Column in big table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have table with 631 columns and 8100 rows. I need to get the `SUM()` for columns 2 to 631, and the total `SUM` for each row.

Small sample from my table

```
code    2   720 729 731 732 737 740 741 743 ....  
------------------------------------------------
28238   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   ....
14840   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ....
25928   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ....
.....   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   ....
```

I need table:
    code    2   720 729 731 732 737 740 741 743 ....  Total

```
-------------------------------------------------------

28238   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   ....   xxx

14840   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ....   xxx

25928   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ....   xxx

.....   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   ....   xxx

total   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   ....
```

Additionally problem: I would need to show only columns where `x = ??` or `x > ??`.

This query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ... 
WHERE code = 'total' AND ( '2' = ?? OR '720' = ?? OR ... in all 631 columns)
```

A very bad idea.

Comment: you can do it doing dynamic sql query , and sp_executesql

Comment: Use reporting software to do it for you.

Comment: In SQL you can combine `x = ?? OR x > ??` to a single `x >= ??`. There is no way around a huge query. I, personally, use Excel to help me write repetitive SQL code: write your query for 3 or 4 column and make sure it is working correctly. Insert list of column names into Excel, then write an Excel formula that produces individual SQL code for each column (e.g. where condition `'2' >= 123 OR`), apply formula to all columns then copy result back to SSMS. Remove trailing `OR` condition from the last column and add brackets as required.

Comment: To be honest, I think there might be a problem in your table design. I can't think of any reason why you would need 631 columns in a single table. I suspect that you could probably split that into two or three related tables with only a few columns each, and that such a change would simplify this query and probably solve a number of other problems too. Though I can't say for sure without knowing what the table is for.

Comment: I need that table for Apriori algorithm (Market Basket Analyzes)
Correctly, there should be 631 rows (users_ID) x 8000 columns (biblio_ID), but SQL Express has a "only 4000 column" constraint
That's why I needed the totals and then the ability to filter through the totals of the columns.
But I already solve this problem by exporting data from SQL databases of the KOHA library system to CSV files and subsequent processing via Python and Pandas